# Overwrite strings file in cocoapod bundle resource

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I am looking for an elegant solution to overwriting an entry in one of my Pods' resource files (specifically a .strings file in a .bundle), probably involving something in `post_install` tasks within my Podfile.

The Pod in question is unfortunately closed-source ([Zendesk SDK](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_ios)) and changing those bundle files manually is their [suggested method](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/customization#customizing-strings-and-localization) of customizing strings.

My Pods folder is currently under source control, so my inelegant solution currently is to log a warning in my Podfile to remind myself to update that resource manually whenever I run `pod install`. I would, however, like to remove my Pods directory from source control, which further necessitates a solution.

Any cocoapods and/or Ruby dudes out there have a nice solution to this silly problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with a solution using `[plutil][1]` (since the .strings files are actually property lists).

In my `Podfile`:

```
  post_install do | installer |          
  system("plutil -replace \"MyPropertyListStringKey" \
          -string "My string goes here" \
          Pods/pathto/Localizable.strings")
  end
```

Comment: Is this command working? I did not. Can you help please. I want to replace ZHMessages.strings in this path "Pods/ZHChat/Resources/ZHCMessagesAssets.bundle/ZHMessages.strings" @Keller